# Delete single cookie in Internet Explorer

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-9

I am currently using IE9(Internet Explorer 9).
In IE9 i can see the I can the particular cookie details by following process..

1)press F12 when IE is opened.So that developer toolbar is opened at bottom
2)click on Cache
3)click on view cookie information
4)then i can see the each cookie detail in next tab opened in IE

Now my requirement is that I want to delete particular cookie from list.
Please provide me solution for the same.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

when you see the view cookie information page then

check the url of that page something line belows

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low\Content.IE5\coocke_xml_file.xml
```

goto that location on you local machine and edit the `<value>` node for the specific Cooke name or delete that node

Answer (score 0):

may this will help you

you need to install IE plugin for this

http://download.cnet.com/IECookiesView/3000-2381_4-10457038.html

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I  tried that plugin also.But the problem is that it deletes the domain in which their may be single or multiple cookies. But my requirement is that to delete single and particular cookie

Comment: its so simple please check my new answer if you are able to do that then don't forget to make answer as acceptable